# Texto na vertical / HTML_CSS

Tags: html5

Quero saber como posso inserir um texto na vertical com CSS, tentei ja colocar

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 25%;
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
vertical-aling:middle;
```

Acho que estou colocando os codigos errados ou no lugar errado, preciso colocar estas 3 listas uma em baixo da outra, agradeço desde já. Nível Iniciante.

```css
menu {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#menu ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Localização</li>
    <li>Portifólio
      <ul>
        <li>Portifólio 01</li>
        <li>Portifólio 02</li>
        <li>Portifólio 03</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Basta remover o `float: left;` que está em `#menu ul li {`, no CSS.

Comment: Você quer o menu na vertical e os subitens abrindo para o lado?

Answer (score 0):

Alterando um pouco seu código, atentando para o uso das tags `<a>` e `<nav>`

Código CSS:

```
/* defina uma largura fixa para todo o menu*/
.navigation {
  width: 100px;
}


/* redefinir suas listas e remove os bullets */
.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/*faça com que todos os links (principal e submenu) tenham preenchimento e cor de fundo */
.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;

}

.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}


/* mouse sobre um item .mainmenu,exiba o submenu dentro dele. mudando a altura máxima do submenu de 0 a 200px; */

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: black;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

/* Este é o estado inicial de todos os submenus.max-height: 0 então, esconde o conteúdo se transbordar*/
.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

Código HTML:

```
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Localização</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Portifólio</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Portifólio 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portifólio 02</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portifólio 03</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Funcionando**

```css
/* defina uma largura fixa para todo o menu*/
.navigation {
  width: 100px;
}


/* redefinir suas listas e remove os bullets */
.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/*faça com que todos os links (principal e submenu) tenham preenchimento e cor de fundo */
.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;

}

.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}


/* mouse sobre um item .mainmenu,exiba o submenu dentro dele. mudando a altura máxima do submenu de 0 a 200px; */

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: black;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

/* Este é o estado inicial de todos os submenus.max-height: 0 então, esconde o conteúdo se transbordar*/
.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Localização</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Portifólio</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Portifólio 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portifólio 02</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portifólio 03</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Muito agradecido amigo, vou estudar um pouco mais sobre a parte da semantica !!

Comment: @JoãoBrasilio Isso! Estude mais semântica. Um conteúdo interessante você pode ver aqui: https://www.devmedia.com.br/html-semantico-conheca-os-elementos-semanticos-da-html5/38065

Comment: @JoãoBrasilio Se a resposta serviu, não deixe de classifica-la como resposta correta que solucionou o seu problema.